# executing an exe from the file list after getting app folder but before the install begins

Tags: inno-setup

I need to extract an exe file to the app folder and run it before the install starts, so I can decide to continue or not. That seems to be the hard part. I can see how a file can be installed in the temp folder, but that will not work for me. 
I am new to Inno setup, I am almost done that is my last hurdle.
I hope someone can help

Comment: *I can see how a file can be installed in the temp folder, but that will not work for me.* - Why? You have to explain us your constraints, otherwise cannot propose a solution.

Comment: OK I understand. This is a Delphi an application using Foxpro tables. To make sure the tables are not opened on the network before I start the upgrade installation. I run a small console application which must run in the install folder. This app tries to open one of the tables in exclusive mode. If this table is already opened, the open fails, and the app creates a small text file to flag the error. Inno can then check for the presence of this text file to cancel the install and tell the user to close the application on the other workstations. Can someone please help. Cheers

Comment: Why the app have to be in the installation folder? Does it look for the files (tables) in the same folder, where the program in located? It's not common. More common is that a program looks for files in its working folder. Isn't that the case?

Comment: Well that is the way it is. I cannot change it. However this does not answer my questions, I am still battling on it. How can I do it with the parameters I mention?

Comment: So you are sure that the program looks for the files in its binary path, not in the working directory? Did you really try it? If you did, use the answer by @kh25.

Comment: FredBuster did my solution work for you? If so mark it as the accepted answer please for future ref.

Answer (score 1):

Try PrepareToInstall() or InitializeSetup():

```
function PrepareToInstall(var NeedsRestart: Boolean): String;
var
  ResultCode: Integer;
begin

  ExtractTemporaryFile('Install.exe');

  if FileCopy(ExpandConstant('{tmp}\Install.exe'), ExpandConstant('{app}\Install.exe'), False) then
  begin
     if not Exec(ExpandConstant('{app}\Install.exe'), '', '', SW_SHOW,  ewWaitUntilTerminated, ResultCode) then 
        Result := 'Installation failed. ' + SysErrorMessage(ResultCode);
  end;
end;
```

Comment: While this answers that the OP asks for, I still do not think it is necessary, see my comments to the question. +1 anyway.